# keycloak not showing ldap child groups

Tags: ldap, keycloak, openldap

I have an LDAP group that contains subgroups. I can view these subgroups when using the Active Directory Users and Computers tool. However, when I use Keycloak 21.0.1 and navigate to the 'Groups' tab and select a group, it does not display the subgroups; it only shows the users belonging to this LDAP group.
Did I overlook something in my User Federation configuration?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]